# Client side scraping when CORS doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, browser, cross-domain, phantomjs, scrape

I have a scenario where [CORS](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/) is not an option for grabbing data to pass back to the server.  I have attempted a few creative workarounds for this, but have kind of hit a wall.  For example, using PhantomJS seems to work in terms of executing it client side to get the ultimate source destination data and then being able to pass that back out, but the codebase is too large to make this feasible.

A lighter client library vs PhantomJS may also be an option, but I've not really found one that fits the bill yet.

Are there any other options that would allow one to get around normal cross domain request limitations for data gathering?

Comment: What codebase is too large to use PhantomJS? Why does it being large prevent you from using PhantomJS?

Comment: Have you tried using yahoo query language?

Comment: Every server side language has some kind of browser, at least cURL. For example there is http://zombie.labnotes.org/ for nodejs, etc...

Comment: Well guys in this case I really need to execute this *client* side (as per the title) and on a per client basis so as to maintain unique IP's per client.  PhantomJS causes a bit too much latency due to its size and I have not really seen an option to use YQL like this.